# Enque and deque deadlocks the channel

Tags: concurrency, go, deadlock, race-condition, goroutine

I am trying to implement a queue, dequeueing and requeueing in a single channel.

I have two questions:

- why do I obtain a deadlock? I was expecting an infinite loop (since I am requeueing even elements which generate more elements and so on). Shouldn't the `range queue` always listening to the channel?
- this is part of the print before the deadloks:

  `enqueueing  1000
  enqueueing  1001
  dequeued  1001
  dequeued  1001
  using  1001
  using  1001`

Are two different goroutines dequeueing the same element? I don't understand why this data race; I thought that the `range`  would pick one per time.

[Code in Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/eWAeocxUEU)

```
func main() {

    queue := make(chan int)
    start := 10

    go func() { queue <- start }()

    for element := range queue {
        fmt.Println("dequeued ", element)
        go enqueue(element, queue)
    }
}

func enqueue(element int, queue chan int) {
    fmt.Println("using ", element)
    if element%2 == 0 {
        fmt.Println("creating new elements from ", element)
        var news = []int{element * 100, element*100 + 1}

        for _, new := range news {
            fmt.Println("enqueueing ", new)
            go func() { queue <- new }()
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: if you change `go func() { queue <- new }()` to `queue <- new` it will keep running, I have not quite figured out why yet.

Comment: twotwotwo's answer cleared it up for me, using `go func() {queueu <- new}()` created a scope issue and by removing the go routing removed the scope issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a scope problem. This happens a *lot* when getting started with `go func() {...}`; it might be more common than real problems with concurrency. There are sections in [the FAQ](http://golang.org/doc/faq#closures_and_goroutines) and [the Go wiki](https://code.google.com/p/go-wiki/wiki/CommonMistakes#Closures) about it.

The anonymous `func` you create gets a reference to a *variable* in the outer scope, not to its *value* at the time the `func` statement runs. And that loop variable is updated each pass through the loop, so it changes between your `go` statement and when the goroutine actually runs.

You can work around this by declaring another variable during each iteration of the loop (i.e., inside the `for` braces). If your loop was `for i := range arr {...}` you could just add `i := i`. So, this bad version:

```
arr := make([]int, 10)
for i := range arr {
    go func() { 
        fmt.Println(i)
    }()
}
```

...[always prints 9](http://play.golang.org/p/zczCgsK_xe). A fixed version, redeclaring `i` inside the loop:

```
arr := make([]int, 10)
for i := range arr {
    i := i
    go func() { 
        fmt.Println(i)
    }()
}
```

...[prints 0-9](http://play.golang.org/p/zTf9Uxb3BZ). A different, arguably more elegant way to redeclare `i` is to make it a param of the anonymous `func`; then it's not a weird-looking standalone statement:

```
arr := make([]int, 10)
for i := range arr {
    go func(i int) { 
        fmt.Println(i)
    }(i)
}
```

[Here's that code](http://play.golang.org/p/5Ujz8GARXA). For all of the Playground versions, I had to add synchronization so `main` wouldn't exit before the goroutines run.

It's confusing that a declaration that "runs" once each time through the loop behaves differently (weird way for scope to manifest) but the way to get around it is straightforward enough.

---

In your case: `queue <- new` can run at any time, and it turns out to run after you've gone through the `for _, new` loop entirely. However, it uses whatever the value of `new` is *as of when it actually runs*, not *as of when the go statement was executed*. In this case, both the goroutines you start get the value 1001, the so second time through both values passed into enqueue are odd (you can see that as two `using 1001`s in your output) so nothing writes to the queue, so there is nothing for the `range queue` loop to consume. The channel isn't closed either, so the `main` can't just end, so you get a deadlock.

You want a *different* value to be "captured" for each execution of the goroutine. For that, you can put `new := new` at the top of the loop, as funny as that looks. That's enough to make the value from each iteration a "different `var`" from Go's perspective, so you get `1000` and `1001` inserted in the channel.

Once you've actually got it working, the Playground won't actually run your code successfully because it loops forever and there are a zillion goroutines running and I guess the Playground doesn't like that (overusing resources).  If you add a limit of 100 elements dequeued before quitting, you get http://play.golang.org/p/bBM3uTnvxi . You'll also notice the numbers it outputs get weird because multiplying by 100 each time will eventually overflow the machine's int type, but that's just how it goes writing programs in lowish-level languages.

As a minor thing, you probably don't want to name a variable `new` because that's also the name of a built-in function. It's legal to do so, just confusing. (It can be kind of reflexive to name a length variable `len`, especially if nothing was wrong with that in the language you're coming from.)

Comment: thanks. I think I understand the underlying problem, but I really don't see why `new:=new` fixes the problem. Don't we have the same problem of the goroutine running when it can? Why is this making sure that there is a new value every time? Any link where I could read more about this?

Comment: Yeah, it's confusing. The key thing is that something you declare inside the braces of the loop is a "different variable" each time through. A variable you declared up at function scope, or in the `range` clause, is not. It's covered at https://code.google.com/p/go-wiki/wiki/CommonMistakes#Closures but I don't think that gets into the "deep why" of it much more. (Going to edit some of this into the answer.)

Comment: Added a standalone description of the scope issue, separated from the specifics of the situation (partly because it might be useful to searchers), but tell me if it's still confusing and if there's anything else it might be useful to say.

Comment: much clearer thanks. Maybe I should have done a separate question so I could have accepted it

Comment: I just added a more elegant workaround I saw in a talk: pass the loop variable as a function parameter, which has the same effect as a redeclaration like `i := i`, but makes it more obvious you're doing something related to your use of an anonymous function.

Answer (score 0):

> why do I obtain a deadlock? I was expecting an infinite loop (since I am requeueing even elements which generate more elements and so on). Shouldn't the range queue always listening to the channel?

When a range loop over a channel reaches the end of the channel's buffer (if the channel has one) it will block, waiting for more elements to be sent through the channel. If there are no other running or runnable goroutines then we've reached a deadlock.

Minimal example:

http://play.golang.org/p/Vb4-RFEmm3

```
package main

func main() {

    queue := make(chan int)

    for _ = range queue {
    }
}
```

> Are two different goroutines dequeueing the same element?

No. What's happening is that this line (26):

```
go func() { queue <- new }()
```

instructs Go's runtime to schedule a new goroutine, it does not necessarily execute immediately. When the goroutine effectively runs, `new`'s value is 1001, not 1000 as printed.